# bash DEBUG trap is not inherited by subshell despite set -T

Tags: bash, trap

I'm using:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Given:

```
#!/bin/bash
validate() {
    if [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" == whoami ]]; then
        echo "whoami detected!"
    fi
}
$ set -T
$ trap 'validate' DEBUG
$ shopt -s extdebug
```

then if I write `whoami`, I get "whoami detected".

If I use a script however:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
```

and run it:

```bash
./script.sh
```

I don't get the message.

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> -T
> If set, any trap on DEBUG and RETURN are inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, **and commands executed in a subshell environment**. The DEBUG and RETURN traps are normally not inherited in such cases.

Why is it not working?

Please note that `whoami` is only for illustration purposes.

Comment: The script doesn't run in a subshell. It runs in a shell that is a subprocess, but that doesn't make it a subshell. See the Stackoverflow question ["Do bash scripts execute in new shells or subshells?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769217/do-bash-scripts-execute-in-new-shells-or-subshells)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Oh, thank you, fair enough. Any way to get it working for a subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a script with `./script.sh` doesn't run it in a subshell, but in a new shell that won't inherit shell state (like traps) from the parent shell. See my answer to the Stackoverflow question ["Do bash scripts execute in new shells or subshells?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769217/do-bash-scripts-execute-in-new-shells-or-subshells) for more details.

If you want to run a script in a subshell, you can use `( )` to create a subshell, and `source` or `.` to run the script in that subshell:

```
(source script.sh)
```

Note that since this is running the script within a parent shell's context, some things will be different from running it normally (with it's own shell). For one thing, its shebang line will be ignored, including any options that're part of it (e.g. if the shebang line is `#!/bin/bash -u`, but you `source` it from zsh, it'll run in zsh without the `-u` option set). There may be other differences/anomalies depending on exactly what the script does.